# What is the difference between Win32 Project vs Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In Visual Studio, when I go to add a project, there are two options for creating GUI applications. Win32 Project and Windows Forms Application. What's the difference between these two? Is one of them

- dependent on more .dlls than the other?
- faster than the other?
- easier to program in than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Win32 are native applications primarly written with C++. (Machine dependent). Windows Forms are managed-code applications using the .NET Runtime Environment.

Between both, Windows forms are easier to program given the fact that you can choose the language you are better with; the vast amount of libraries (BCL) without bizarre things like manual memory management and the real object-oriented paradigm implementation of many of them.

Comment: Hmm. That's what I originally thought, but then after creating a new Win32 Project and I went into its properties, it said Targetted Framework: .NETFramework,Version=v4.0